# Efficient way to store and fetch a list of objects

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, data-structures, postgresql-9.4

I have an application in spring boot that handles custom requests. 
And there exists a scheduled job running every 30 sec and it fetches a list of objects from db and performs certain operations. 
I get freaked out thinking that I need to query the database for every 30 seconds, and instead I could keep these objects in a data structure.
There are rest APIs that adds or deletes or edits the properties of these objects and therefore, I would need to handle update of these objects 
In the data structure as well. Which approach should I go for ?

The size of the objects can be anything between 100 - 10000. I use Postgres as my db.

Comment: Try looking this and find some good in memory db: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439958/highest-performance-database-in-java

Comment: If you integrate an ORM to your project this would be a simple task. then you can use 2nd level cache.

Comment: How large is your query? Worrying about a database hit every 30 seconds sounds exaggerated, when you consider that databases perform thousands of transactions per second.

Comment: It is a simple select statement  something like 'SELECT distinct(name, id) from table'. May be I am just being paranoid here

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you will need to save the data to a custom data structure, instead you could take a look at Hibernate's 2nd level cache for both entities and queries.

With proper settings the Hibernate will cache the data and the query you are using for you.

[There](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache) is good article on Baeldung about 2nd level cache that can get you started.

Comment: Hibernate is not used in my application, rather I use JDBCTemplate.

Comment: Sorry, my bad that I assumed the use of Hibernate with Spring Boot, however I think there is an implementation of JDBC Caching in the EHCache dependency anyway - you can look at that, it should work in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you should write a database listener that listens on DB records change event then fetches the records in the data structure of your choice then caches the records to be used in case the DB change event isn't triggered

- this is a good [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618915/how-to-implement-a-db-listener-in-java) on how to implement db listener in java